# Quando e quem introduziu ou padronizou a pontuação na língua portuguesa?

Tags: origem-histórica, pontuação

Ao ver uma fotografia da carta escrita por Pero Vaz de Caminha ao rei D. Manuel I em 1500 CE, comunicando o descobrimento de novas terras, percebo a ausência de sinais de pontuação. Outros documentos também do século XVI demonstram a falta de pontuação.  Pergunto então: quando e quem pela primeira vez padronizou os sinais de pontuação na língua escrita?  Quais foram os primeiros sinais?  Quais os últimos a serem acrescentados?

Comment: Não sou bom de ler texto antigo, mas vejo uma vírgula na primeira linha da [carta](https://digitarq.arquivos.pt/viewer?id=4185836), «posto que o capitão**,**». Nesta [cantiga](https://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/cantiga.asp?cdcant=66&pv=sim) galego-portuguesa acho que também há. Do século XVI, tens [Os Lusíadas](https://purl.pt/1/1/index.html#/1/html), de Camões, recheado de pontuações. Se eu não me engano, a história da pontuação é bem extensa e complexa. Acho que os romanos já meio que a tinham. Adoraria ver uma resposta.

Comment: @Schilive   "Os Lusíadas"  foi publicado mais de 70 anos após a carta de Caminha.  Será que a edição original já continha vírgulas e pontos ?

Comment: Andei a ver, e havia quem usasse pontuação (diferente da nossa) já no século XIV, mas naqueles tempos cada um escrevia, e pontuava (ou não), à sua maneira. Ainda assim, eu vejo para lá uns pontos na carta do Pero, mas como eu não consigo ler aquilo -- não compreendo a letra -- não sei se são pontuação ou não. A edição d'Os Lusíadas que o @Schilive linkou é a primeira, de 1572. o manuscrito da cantiga creio que é medieval. Eu vejo lá pontos, mas a maioria não faz sentido como pontuação.

Comment: No texto que @Schilive "linkou", eu vejo também um ponto final na quarta linha, a seguir à segunda palavra. E depois mais outro a meio do parágrafo... mas nenhum no fim do parágrafo? Se calhar por ser redundante? Não sei. Também não consigo ler o texto, por isso não me quero pôr a adivinhar.

Comment: Já vi esta pergunta respondida no site. Mas de preferência o post devia incluir um link para o documento digitalizado.

Comment: Tem certeza, @bad_coder ? Não consegui achar.

Comment: A introdução da pontuação antecede o próprio português. Sua padronização se deu de forma gradual, [estimulada](https://www.scielo.br/j/delta/a/x9BCkcRYFdp3jTYjzf5mmQk/?lang=pt) pela imprensa, nos séculos XV e XVI, e [se estabelecendo](https://educacao.uol.com.br/disciplinas/portugues/sinais-de-pontuacao-origem-historica-dos-sinais.htm) de fato no século XVII. Haveria [pouca diferença](https://www.britannica.com/topic/punctuation/Punctuation-in-English-since-1600) entre as línguas europeias ocidentais, dada a influência de impressores italianos e franceses.

Comment: Eu acho que tem um livro que fala sobre a história da pontuação. Era estilizado e tinha linguagem extensa, e era grande. Não consigo achar de novo.